# Vue JS computed property not available yet when component renders

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a page using **Vue JS**. Within the Vue instance I have a computed property that builds an array of map points, and then a Vue component in the page that uses the computed property calculated in the root instance.

However the computed property is not available yet at the time the component is rendered,which throws an error on the computed property: **"error during evaluation"**

If I comment out the Vue component, the computed property calculates correctly.

However with the component added, the computed property is not yet available, and I receive the following error: **"Cannot read property of undefined"**

```
<google-map class="google-map" :markers="points"></google-map>
```

---

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

import { crudFunctionsMixin } from './mixin-crud-functions.js';

Vue.component('google-map', require('../GoogleMaps/GoogleMap').default);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#App',
    mixins: [ crudFunctionsMixin ],
    data: () => ({
        model: "prospect",
        modelName: "Prospect",
        modelNamePlural: "Prospects",
        pagination: {
            sortBy: 'name'
        },
        headers: [
            { text: 'ID', value: 'id', sortable: true },
            { text: 'Name', value: 'name', sortable: true },
            { text: 'Food Category', value: 'foodcat_id', sortable: true },
            { text: 'Contact', value: 'contact_lname', sortable: true },
            { text: 'Admin Comments', value: 'response_notes', sortable: true },
            { sortable: false }
        ]
    }),
    computed: {
        tblFilteredItems: function() {
            return this.$refs.prospectsTable.filteredItems;
        },
        points: function() {
            return this.calcPoints(this.$refs.prospectsTable.filteredItems);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        calcPoints(items) {
            let myPts = [];

            items.forEach(function(prospect) {
                if(prospect.latitude && prospect.longitude) {
                    myPts.push({
                        id:     prospect.id,
                        position: {
                            lat: prospect.latitude,
                            lng: prospect.longitude
                        },
                        title:  prospect.address + ", " + prospect.city + ", " + prospect.zip,
                        icon:   "\/img\/numberedMapIcons\/number_" + prospect.id + ".png"
                    });
                }
            });

            return myPts;
        },

        fetch() {
            $.get(`/${this.model}/fetch`, (r) => {
                if(r.successMsg) {
                    this.collection = r.collection.data;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
app.fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try:

1: Use a v-if to conditionally render the map if you have data.

```
`<google-map v-if="points.length" :markers="points" class="google-map" />`
```

- You could use a v-else then to render a loading symbol of some kind.

2: In your computed you can check if you have data already, as I guess this where your undefined problem is coming from.

```
points: function() {
  if (!this.$refs.prospectTable.filteredItems) return [];
  return this.calcPoints(this.$refs.prospectsTable.filteredItems);
}
```

Comment: When I add this, I get this error [ Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filteredItems' of undefined" ]. It appears that the "prospectsTable" reference is not yet available.